# Why open weather shell extension is diabled in Gnome Tweak Tool?

Tags: 20.04, gnome, gnome-shell-extension

In Gnome Tweak Tool, I'm unable to change the enable open weather:

[image]

Comment: the triangle icon/symbol indicates that there is a problem with the extension. try to uninstall the extension. Download it from gnome-extensions web page for your particular gnome-shell version and try. https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/750/openweather/ I installed in the same way in Ubuntu 20.04 and it is working for me. https://i.stack.imgur.com/60lae.jpg

Answer (score 1):

This triangle indicates a problem with the extension. So first, remove the version you currently have installed.

Some extensions are available in the software repository of Ubuntu. This is the safest way to install and use extensions, because these have been packaged and tested for your particular Ubuntu version. Install the weather extension using

```
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-weather
```

or using the Snap store.

Be careful if you install extensions (and any software) outside of the Ubuntu software repositories. Newer versions may not anymore work on your version of Gnome Shell. Make sure to select a version that is compatible with your version of Gnome Shell. You can see your current version of Gnome Shell in Settings - About.